# How to listen for firebase realtime database update event in background and auto start app (Like calliing feature in messenger) with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chat application with flutter, and we're using firebase realtime database to know when a user is calling another user. The problem is that we need to listen for it when the app is not active (ie closed or running in the background). How do I achieve this with flutter? I am not familiar with android and I am just a beginner in flutter.

Answer (score 2):

What I would suggest is to implement Push notifications.

That way, you can use your cloud functions to send your user a push notification if something changed, they can click on it, and it will open the app and get the latest data.

Just listening isn't possible as IOS and later versions of android stops background apps from going crazy.

Comment: But i can't let the users know that another user is calling just through push notifications. I need to be able to show a incoming call screen.

Comment: FCM has two types of messages: 1) notification messages, which the system handles automatically when the app is not active, 2) data messages, for which code in a broadcast receiver in your application is called. By sending a data message, you can show the correct UI when the message is received.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know.